# CSS transform not working in active link

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform, internet-explorer-11

I'm having a weird problem with a website. I used CSS3 transform (translate) to produce the "pressed" effect in buttons when they're in `:active` state. Everything works great in *all* browsers except IE 11, even though I used all vendor prefixes (including `-ms-`) & the standard without prefix. Is there any way to accomplish the same effect in IE 11?

```css
#nav-bar li:not(.active-page):active {
    -webkit-transform: translate(4px, 4px);
    -moz-transform: translate(4px, 4px);
    -ms-transform: translate(4px, 4px);
    -o-transform: translate(4px, 4px);
    transform: translate(4px, 4px);
}
```

Comment: `Do you need the code?` Yes please :)

Comment: jsfiddle example would be beneficial

Answer (score 7):

*Note: The following applies only to Internet Explorer. This bug has been [resolved in Microsoft Edge](https://twitter.com/jonathansampson/status/609099096729595904).*

#### Final Answer

As stated in the comments below, the original (unprovided) source had nested anchors immediately within the list items. The following should serve as a good example:

```html
<nav id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="active-page"><a href="/home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="/online-resume">My Resume</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

It's important to note that neither the CSS 2.1 specification or the Selectors Level 3 module state whether the `:active` state applies to an element's parent as well:

> CSS does not define which elements may be in the above states, or how the states are entered and left. Scripting may change whether elements react to user events or not, and different devices and UAs may have different ways of pointing to, or activating elements. **CSS 2.1 does not define if the parent of an element that is ':active' or ':hover' is also in that state**.
>
> — CSS 2.1 Specification, [Section 5.11.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes)

> There may be document language or implementation specific limits on which elements can become :active or acquire :focus... **Selectors doesn't define if the parent of an element that is ‘:active’ or ‘:hover’ is also in that state**.
>
> — Selectors Level 3, [Section 6.6.1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#the-user-action-pseudo-classes-hover-act)

With the above in mind, we have no expectation that all browsers will apply the `:active` pseudo-class not only to an anchor element currently being activated, but also to the anchor's parent(s). Unfortunately, in this case, Chrome and Firefox appear to *bubble up* the pseudo-class, while Internet Explorer does not.

While this isn't a mistake in spec implementation, I will be opening an *Interop Bug* for our team to look at (these are important issues to us). In the meantime, you can create the functionality you are seeking with just a bit of scripting. I'll be using jQuery below:

```js
(function ($) {

    "use strict";

    $("#nav-bar").on({
        "mousedown mouseup": function () { $(this).toggleClass("pressed"); },
        /* mouseleave just incase "mouseup" happens outside of the anchor */
        "mouseleave": function () { $(this).removeClass("pressed"); }
    }, "li");

}(jQuery));
```

Lastly, just make one adjustment to your selector so that it applies to the `.pressed` class:

```css
#nav-bar li:not(.active-page):active, 
#nav-bar li:not(.active-page).pressed {
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

The end-result appears to be the effect you're looking to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dsy9g2j2/8/

[image]

#### Updated Answer

After discussing the issue further in the comments below, you appear to be using `translate(x, y)` to offset the element rather than *impress* the element. You should not have any issue getting this to work, as Internet Explorer has supported all of the appropriate features for years now.

I took your lead and used the markup/CSS that you alluded to in your comments:

```html
<div id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li class="active-page">One</li>
        <li>Two</li>
        <li>Three</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```css
#nav-bar li:not(.active-page):active {
    transform: translate(10px, 10px);
}
```

As you can see, this works as-is in Internet Explorer with no additional work:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dsy9g2j2/4/

As to why you didn't get these results, it's possible that you did run into a bug. A few months back I filed an issue regarding right-padded y-values in the `translate` function invalidating an entire property value:

```css
transform: translate( 10px, 10px );
```

Note the spaces immediately within the parens - the one before the closing paren invalidates the value in Internet Explorer. Fortunately, our team has resolved this issue and it won't be a problem in future releases, but for now, you'll need to make sure the y-value isn't right-padded with a space.

Fiddle (Expected to be broken): http://jsfiddle.net/dsy9g2j2/5/

#### Original Answer

It sounds like you may be using [`translateZ`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj200289(v=vs.85).aspx) to reduce the size of an element during its `:active` state; if this is the case you'll need to make sure you have a [perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj200271(v=vs.85).aspx) applied to the element directly, or [to its ancestral tree some place](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772272(v=vs.85).aspx). Without perspective the browser cannot determine how pronounced the effect of the translation should be.

```css
.button:active {
    transform: perspective(300px) translateZ(-1em);
}
```

The end result is consistent across all browsers, including Internet Explorer 11:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/dsy9g2j2/3/

Comment: No Jonathan. I'm using plain translate, in fact, I could post the code, but it's useless, because it works in all the other browsers, so it's not a code problem.
In fact, I'm using transform: translate(4px, 4px) with all vendor prefixes & the standard version.
I'm applying it to this selector: #nav-bar li:not(.active-page):active.
I've read somewhere that this is a normal bug in IE when you apply it to li's. In fact, I tried same code with this selector (h1:hover{transform:translate(10px, 10px);} & worked in IE.

Comment: @MarceloMiguelBazan The code you shared *works* in IE 11. See my updated answer above. There is however a bug associated with parsing the y-value from `translate` which you may have hit. I share more about this in my answer above.

Comment: Yes. I tried your code & it worked in IE11 until...I discovered that I didn't say that I've got <a>'s inside the <li>'s, so, as soon as I included the <a>'s your example stopped working.

Comment: @MarceloMiguelBazan This is why it's important to *always* post your code when you ask the question ;) I've updated my answer above.

Comment: Thanks. Next time I'll put the code, even though It sounds silly because, "normally", I'd think: "If I need to move a box from my bedroom to the kitchen, it doesn't matter if it has toys, books or apples inside, I need to move the box as a whole, not the content". Apparently, software gurus don't use the same logic. :(

Comment: @MarceloMiguelBazan It's a bit more complicated than that :)